# Twisted web server on Heroku?

Tags: heroku, cloud, twisted

To get straight down to the point, the main purpose of the app is to work as a backend server for android clients, not a web application. Would it be a good idea to deploy it on Heroku? Or should I consider going down a stack on to IaaS such as AWS?
I ask this because I read somewhere that Heroku's HTTP timeout feature might go against the async-non blocking characteristic of twisted server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Twisted will be fine: it's very much like Ruby's Puma or Node.js, and all are supported.

> Pure Python applications, such as headless processes and evented web frameworks like Twisted, are fully supported.

See here for more info: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-support